# How do we select non-aggregate columns in a query with a GROUP BY clause, which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, group-by

My SQL

```
SELECT 
  `tbl_order`.`order_id` 
FROM `tbl_order` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_rooms` ON `tbl_order`.`room_name` = `tbl_rooms`.`room_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_orderdetails` ON `tbl_order`.`order_key` = `tbl_orderdetails`.`orderdetail_orderkey` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_guestcatlang` ON `tbl_order`.`order_product_type`=`tbl_guestcatlang`.`guestcatlang_guestcat_id`
                             and `tbl_guestcatlang`.`guestcatlang_lang_id`="en"
JOIN `tbl_sitesettings` ON `tbl_order`.`order_setting_id` = `tbl_sitesettings`.`setting_id` 
WHERE
(
  (
    tbl_sitesettings.delayedBrekfast = 1 AND 
   `tbl_order`.`order_product_type` = "BREAKFAST" AND
    (
      `tbl_order`.`order_required_time` > "2018-02-28 18:30:00" AND
      `tbl_order`.`order_required_time` < "2018-03-01 18:29:59" AND
       tbl_sitesettings.delayTime - (unix_timestamp(convert_tz(now(),("UTC"), tbl_sitesettings.timeZone))-unix_timestamp()) < "26100" 
    )
  ) OR
  (
    `tbl_sitesettings`.`delayedBrekfast` != 1 OR
    `tbl_order`.`order_status` = "Complete" OR
     tbl_order.order_product_type != "BREAKFAST"
  )
) AND
`tbl_order`.`order_status` IN('Open') AND
`tbl_order`.`order_product_type` IN('BREAKFAST', 'Room Service', 'AMENITIES', 'GIFT SHOP', 'Internet Plan', 'Device Management',
                                    'System Message', '70', '69', '67', '68', '75', '76', '77', '78',
                                    '93', '94', '95', '97', '98', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105',
                                    '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115',
                                    '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '127',
                                    '128', '135') AND
`tbl_order`.`order_product_type` != 'Recomended Product' AND 
`tbl_order`.`order_setting_id` = '7' 
GROUP BY `tbl_order`.`order_key` 
ORDER BY `tbl_order`.`ordered_time` DESC
```

And this was the error Message

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'ebdb_production.tbl_order.order_id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Any solution ??? :(

Comment: So there is one column called `order_id` and another called `order_key`? And `order_id` is the primary key which you want to select, but you group by `order_key` instead? Why? What is the intention behind that?

Comment: I would expect to see some aggregate functions with a group by.

Comment: Why the three outer joins? They don't influence your result at all. The query would look nicer without all those ugly backticks by the way. And you should use table aliases to get this more readable, too.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try execute the below query. This will remove the restriction of such.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: Is this a permanent solution? This works first, but things gone back to trouble when i restart my apache. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Its not the problem with apache but with MySQL. There are ways to make it permanent by setting this in MySQL.ini file. Or, you will have to execute it whenever MySQL is restarted.